# Disable current timestamp on updateAt feild at update query in postgres with sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In My Sequelize Model Definition,

```
const userEpisodeListen = sequelize.define(
    'userEpisodeListen',
    {},
    {
      timestamp: false,
    }
  );
```

Comment: Are you using paranoid for updation of current timestamp on updateAt field ?

Comment: No, Actually now I am not using paranoid for updation, will paranoid effect for this updateAt felild?

Comment: The way you are doing is correct, are you sure you are not using  timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt) in your model.

Comment: To get rid of createdAt, updatedAt fields you should use timestamps: false (plural form, not singular)

Comment: This is my updatedAt datatypes while creating table: 
updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },

Comment: @vasylOk I have tried this but this is also not worked for me. this will ignore updatedAt and createdAt. but I actually want to update updatedAt. but not with current timestamp. I want to update updatedAt feild with some different dates which I will pass.

Comment: Why don't you disable the default functionality alltogether as suggested and go ahead and put the field you  you want updatedAt in your model and manipulate it in your resolver the way you wish?